# Enhance DataSourceProperties configuration bean with KMS provided secret

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud-gcp

I want to set the password for the datasource programatically and still use auto configuration of Spring GCP and Spring Data.

**Background**

I want to obtain my password as encrypted blob and decrypt it via Google KMS. I read that spring gcp auto configuration mutates the `DataSourceProperties` bean to apply gcp secific configurations (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_jdbc.html#_literal_datasource_literal_creation_flow).

Now I would like to mutate the `DataSourceProperties` Bean exposed by `GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration` once more.
Exposing the `DataSourceProperties` as follows does not work because `GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration` then doesn't know which Bean to take: the one configured by spring boot auto configuration or mine. But mine should be applied in the very last step of configuration.

```
@Bean
public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    dataSourceProperties.setPassword(getDecryptedSecret());
    return dataSourceProperties;
}

private String getDecryptedSecret() {
    // get encrypted password and decrypt it
    return "myDecryptedPassword"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to provide your own bootstrap property source that contains a value for `spring.datasource.password`.

See: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources

Full answer is on project GitHub: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2330

Answer (score 0):

Cloud KMS offers encrypting and decrypting data with a symmetric key[1] and/or an asymmetric key[2].

You can see DataSourceProperties[3] for more of the supported options for Spring Boot.

[1]-https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt

[2]-https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt-rsa

[3]-https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java

Comment: Hm the challenge still remains: one needs to configure the datasource to use that password.

Comment: Are you using secret management solutions [1]. You can store a secret in a Cloud Storage bucket [2] encrypted at the application layer with an encryption key from Cloud Key Management Service, as an example.
[1]-https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/secret-management#choosing_a_secret_management_solution
[2]-https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/store-secrets

Comment: The problematic part is to expose the `DataSourceProperties` Bean which is already enhanced by Spring GCP auto configuration and exposed with `@Primary`. Maybe my ticket description is a bit misleading.

Comment: I updated my description. It should by clear now what my problem is. It is rather Spring Auto Configuration specific than google cloud.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Cloud KMS offers encryption and decryption feature as posted. You can check the options of the DataSourceProperties.

Comment: I want to tie in with Spring GCP SQL Autoconfiguration (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/autoconfigure/sql/GcpCloudSqlAutoConfiguration.java#L141) and just set the password after it has configured the relevant things. When I expose my own `DataSourceProperties` which is injected there, it does not work, as described.